# Alternative to "let me know"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-requests

I want to use something better than "letting me know" in this sentence:

> Please reply letting me know what day/time works best for you if are still interested, if you need a later date, or if you are no longer interested.

Comment: "Please let me know ..."

Comment: Keep it short. day/time is OK; don't worry about "elegance".  Without knowing what interaction went before, we can't prescribe exactly what you should say in its entirety, but "Please let me know what day/time works best for you."  is probably the way to end your e-mail.

Answer (score 3):

It will be easier to replace "let me know" if we use the substitute to replace "reply". That information is probably redundant since compliance with the request would require a reply of some sort anyway.

If we do that, I think "[notify](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=notify&use1828=on)" works well in this context because "[notices](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=notice&resource=Webster%27s&word=notify&use1828=on)" are a very formal method of informing people. It can places some special emphasis on the textual nature of the correspondence, albeit without strictly requiring a textual reply. As long as I have mentioned it, "[inform](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=notice&resource=Webster%27s&word=inform&use1828=on)" is another good word for providing knowledge as well.

Here's a minimal change from the initial example:

> Please notify me with what day/time works best for you if are still interested, if you need a later date, or if you are no longer interested.

As an aside, it seems like you have a prearranged date, so I would suggest also considering:

> Please notify me if you are still interested. If you are interested but need a later date, inform me with a later date & time that is better for you.

I personally prefer the more elegant appearance of the ampersand, over the utilitarian look of the slash, especially in the context of an invitation. I also think splitting the rescheduling from the interest check with a separate [conditional sentence](http://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/~kay/bcg/lec07.html) also makes the sentiment a little easier to parse, one bit at a time.

---

> **Linked Resources:**
>
> Most definitions are retrieved from the [American Dictionary of the English Language by Noah Webster, 1828](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/).
>
> rsvp. (n.d.) American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. (2011). Retrieved from [The Free Dictionary by Farlex](http://www.thefreedictionary.com).
>
> [Berkley Construction Grammar](http://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/~kay/bcg/ConGram.html) Lecture Outline #7 by [Professor Charles J. Filmore of The University of Berkley](http://linguistics.berkeley.edu/charles-j-fillmore-1929-2014).

Answer (score 2):

Be positive - assume they are still interested.  Emphasizing disinterest will make them start to wonder if they should be disinterested.

What date/time would work for you to ....*go over this, meet and discuss*...or whatever it is that you are trying to do.

Comment: Is that disinterest (a lack of bias) or uninterest (a lack of enthusiasm or commitment)?

Answer (score 1):

**Question:** "How would you like to proceed?"

**Comment:** "Please advise."

**Directive:** "Awaiting your reply."

Answer (score 0):

What you have would sound fine to me, but if you want to change it, perhaps say "Please reply by letting..."

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple and direct.  Just ask - What day/time works for you.